# PostgreSQL - find all functions and stored procedures with permissions granted to PUBLIC

Tags: sql, postgresql

In Postgres SQL how can I find (via an SQL query) all functions and stored procedures for which `PUBLIC` has any permissions on them (e.g. to execute them or to do anything with them)?

If it matters my Postgres version is this one:

`PostgreSQL 11.13 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

In other words when a function/procedure is scripted out, sometimes I see this line in its source code:

`GRANT ... ON FUNCTION some_function() TO public;`

So I want to find all such functions in my DB which when scripted out show this line.

Comment: Hmm, this sounds like where this thread on pgsql-general [Grant usage](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/0994D6C4-EDF0-4854-B528-88DDE429172E%40yugabyte.com) ended up. Where a possible solution is presented here [Public functions](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/0994D6C4-EDF0-4854-B528-88DDE429172E%40yugabyte.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found a solution myself. Here it is.

```
select routine_schema, routine_name, * 
from information_schema.role_routine_grants rrg 
where 
grantee  ilike '%public%'
order by routine_schema asc, specific_name asc, routine_name asc
```